# Editing misguided questions vs changing their meaning

Tags: discussion, edits

1. **If question is clearly about A, but is asking for it using term B, meaning something else, is an edit that changes B to A *really* changing the intent?**
2. If so, do we prefer confusing questions to be left only for their author to correct?
3. If so, why?

In edit guidelines I read that good reason to edit post is

> to clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

I've cut all the case specifics, since it seemed to have a detrimental effect to my question, it got folks focused on question I edited and that was less relevant for me actually than general rules. 
For the sake of completeness, I've edited a question that asked about Java Memory Management (term A) but used Java Memory Model (term B) to describe what it asked for. My edit was rejected on grounds of changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: That question should be closed as off-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: A memory model and  memory management are different IMHO. I think I would have choosen to leave a comment to ask clearification. And in the mean time search for a duplicate to close the question against.

Comment: Well, the problems with the question itself trump any editing concerns.  It's three years old, Too Broad, and a request for external resources.  Generally, the community favors taking the correct action (in this case, a vote to close) over clarifying the title and tags of a fundamentally broken question.

Comment: I've cut nearly all the specifics of my edit, beside those that serve my actual questions. Thanks to all commenters for pointing out what really should happen with edited question, I flagged it as you suggested.

Comment: I saw your edit, but I think you will find that if you apply sound editing principles to questions that are actually on-topic, the case becomes much clearer and more apparent.  To answer your prima facie question: if it is clear that changing the wording of the question would clarify the actual question being asked, of course such an edit would be valid.  I didn't see any such clarity in your edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The general principle is clear but these X/Y questions are quite frequently observed. Even if you know what the questioner really wanted you would still need to modify the original question heavily to make it more clear. Are these large scale edits really wanted by SO? Or is the risk of doing something wrong higher? Since I stil see them around I guess that people (also above 2K rep) rather do not change them even if they could.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't review the edit, but I'm not sure if I would have approved it either. As an occasional Java user, I frankly was not aware that "Java Memory Model" has a very precise meaning in the Java world. After doing a search on it, I understand your change now.

In most contexts, "model" is a fairly generic term, and it would seem valid talking about the "memory model" when discussing how a certain programming language deals with memory management. So at first sight, I did not see anything wrong with the original terminology.

This is a general challenge with the SO review system. The reviewers will often not be specialists on the topics of the posts. Most reviews can be done without understanding all the technical details, but there are cases where people make the wrong decision. The best strategy would be for reviewers to skip those reviews. But that has its own set of problems, because many edits tend to be approved blindly. So the reviewers who try to be thorough often don't want to skip questionable edits, and give the infamous "robo reviewers" a chance to approve them.

Another reason why I might have declined (or at least modified) your edit is that the resulting text does not sound good to me:

> The Java memory management is a huge topic in Java.

Changing this to the following simplifies the sentence, and makes it much less awkward:

> Memory management is a huge topic in Java.

And, last not but least, the question is **off topic** for Stack Overflow. So the right action would have been to flag it instead of editing it.

Comment: I get why flagging is good and have flagged it. However... would we want to leave a misleading question as it is - adding more to confusion? Perhaps I'm too much of a perfectionist?