# Editing title of old question with incorrect terminology

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I'm looking for a way to *throttle* JavaScript callbacks with jQuery, and am finding questions like these:

[How to throttle callback of jQuery event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366043/how-to-throttle-callback-of-jquery-event)

[Throttle event calls in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373023/throttle-event-calls-in-jquery)

Those questions are not actually how to *throttle*, they are how to *debounce*.  And, they have answers that provide methods for debouncing (and not throttling).

They have a reasonable amount of upvotes, which suggests people may be finding them by searching for the incorrect term.  But, for people searching for answers using the correct term (throttling), it's frustrating to find these questions and discover it's for debouncing.

What is the recommended course of action in this case?

1. Edit the title to the correct terminology?
2. Leave a comment pointing out the inaccuracy?
3. Leave it alone and just accept that's how some people think about the question?
4. Something else I've not considered?

I want to be a good steward with SO content, so I hope to get some "authoritative" advice on what the SO policy is / should be in this case.

**Note**
I've reviewed various other questions here on Meta, including [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem) - but am not finding one that matches my concern.

Comment: I'd take the option to edit, as long it doesn't invalidate anything in the OP or answers.

Comment: Interesting.  I am tempted to do so.  It would actually make the OP and answers **more** accurate / correct.

Comment: I want to edit your title... for another reason

Comment: dunno.... seems like a bad situation. Very few devs looking for debounce that don't know it's called debounce will find those questions if they're changed from throttle to debounce. In some of those cases, a throttle would likely be an acceptable answer too.

Comment: Related: [Editing misguided questions vs changing their meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271365/4642212).

Answer (score 5):

I'd leave the title alone. 
The title is for optimizing future generations' Google searches.

"Debounce" looks like the *answer*, but not something anyone would intuitively pose as a *question* - I, for one, have never heard of the term and if I had this question, my first search  would absolutely be for `throttle jquery events`.

A clarifying comment to each question might be valuable: you could provide a helpful link for those looking for actual throttling and not debouncing.

Comment: Which was my "gut" feeling (leave the title alone).  A comment with a link seems like the cleanest way without disrupting future searchers.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing to do in this case is to use tags. Remove [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throttle) from every [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345864) where it does not apply. And then add [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing).

This will allow you to use an "advanced search" to get highly relevant results (as soon as the changes propagate to the search engine):

[`jQuery throttle callback -debounce -debouncing site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+throttle+callback+-debounce+-debouncing+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=jQuery+throttle+callback+-debounce+-debouncing+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Or if you are using the built in search:

[`[jquery] -[debouncing] throttle callback -debounce`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D++throttle+callback+-%5Bdebouncing%5D+-debounce)

---

Additionally, you should close these questions as duplicates when applicable. Make sure the target has the right wording, but you can leave the "poor" wording for the other questions.

The very reason we have the ability to close as duplicates is to keep a record of all those alternate ways people ask the question, and point them towards a single source of answers. This way, there is still a way to navigate when searching for the incorrect terminology.