# Should I edit the title of my question, since it could be misleading?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing-help

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62648723/4375327) whose title assumes the behavior of a command. However, it was obvious this was not the case I stated (the command doesn't set a *variable* on exit, it sets a *status code*).

The body of the question, however, is more factual.

I'm thinking about future readers. Should I edit the title which could be misleading?

---

**Update.**
As asked in the comment section, the subject is close to another SOM question: *[Editing misguided questions vs changing their meaning](http://Editing%20misguided%20questions%20vs%20changing%20their%20meaning)*.

However, it's about a *misuse of terms*. The [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62648723/4375327) I was talking about was phrased as if it assumes a behavior which wasn't. (Due to an unexpected negative ErrorLevel, I closed my mind on thining the command touches a variable rather than setting a internal error level.)

By the way, the [unique answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271366/4375327) doesn't provide a real solution, it tells about the struggle about finding a "good" editing, IMHO.

Comment: Related: [Editing title of old question with incorrect terminology](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326597/4642212), [Tagging a question based on its answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079/4642212), [Editing misguided questions vs changing their meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271365/4642212).

Comment: change it, if it fits better. nobody will mind it

Comment: @nbk, it's done. Feedbacks welcome.

Comment: to be honest, because of a typo

Comment: you got the result -1 and tested against bigger than 1, that is a typo and so not reproducible

Comment: @nbk it was not a typo, you can read the answer and my comment below it to understand what happened. Afterwards I rephrased the title to not mislead future readers.

Comment: Looks like you've edited the title yourself already, so this appears to be resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing misguided questions vs changing their meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271365/editing-misguided-questions-vs-changing-their-meaning)

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName The subject is close but not the same: the question you linked is about a misuse of terms. My question was phrased like it assumes a behavior which wasn't. Due to an unexpected negative ErrorLevel, I closed my mind on thining the command touches a variable rather than setting a internal error level. Btw the answerer doesn't provide a real solution, it tells about the struggle about finding a "good" editing, IMHO.

Comment: Your new title isn't particularly helpful either.  Google users will arrive at your post thinking it's about how to retrieve an exit status of InstallUtil with ERRORLEVEL, when it's not about that at all; it's about a very specific error you got while trying to retrieve an exit status of InstallUtil with ERRORLEVEL.  We get these kinds of titles all the time, and they're a useless time sink for people trying to find an answer to their problem by googling it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the question, and especially the accepted answer deal with this subject. Also it was an information difficult to retrieve (I only found [this Microsoft forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/fr-FR/7a69f180-b3f9-476b-bd7b-27ec7d36e06c/installutil-return-codes?forum=winformssetup) evasively referring to it. Now this question is the first in the Google result. But if you're thinking about a better title, that's ok for me.